# Scala 3 - Sonar - Not getting unit tests coverage

Tags: scala, testing, sonarqube, sbt, code-coverage

I am using sbt-sonar 2.2.0 with Scala 3.3.1.
I have a code with for comprehension and pattern matching and created tests for it. When I debugged it, all lines are covered and I certified that running with coverage at Intellij (result = 100%). I runned tests at the environment with data and the code is reached.

I can post any code because it is confidential.

Does any faced it with for comprehension?

**UPDATE:**
The case was not solved but at least I know the limits now (december/23)

This mismatching coverage occurs only with sbt coverage, sonar and Scala 3. And it happens when:

- there's a command that fills 2 or more lines
- there's a flatMap
- there's a for comprehension inside the method (and not right after the method is declared)
- there's a "match" command
- besides, the line numbers at sonar are also decreased by 2 comparing with source code

The same problem was discussed [here](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/coverage-broken-why-does-nobody-care/6262/9), and nothing more than Martin Odersky (Scala author) was involved.

Solutions for this moment: only avoid the commands above and creating method for any uncovered line. It seems that when you created a method, sonar recognized the coverage

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? No need to share real code. Maybe an small POC that replicate the issue you are having

Comment: The latest release of [sbt-sonar](https://github.com/sonar-scala/sbt-sonar) was on May 22, 2021. The repo si marked as archived. [sonar-scala](https://github.com/sonar-scala/sonar-scala) is also marked as archived and in the README says "Intended for SonarQube 9.4, SonarQube 8.9 LTS, SonarQube 7.9 LTS, SonarQube 6.7 LTS and Scala 2.11/2.12/2.13".

Comment: If you go to the docs of [sonar - languages - scala](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/scala/) in the related pages about test coverage it mention [scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin). If you check the docs of that plugin it says that is compatible with sonar and also with scala 3

Comment: @GastónSchabas it was a incompatibility with sonar and Scala3. I gave more details at the subject and for now, the solution is really ignoring or changing all your code